# Is it necessary to emit event, while there is no event? Error called "No events were emitted" in Solidity Truffle test

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

No clue if there should be an event specified or how to create a function with balanceOf. Can't pass Truffle test.

Hello,
this is my first smart contract, aimed to create an ERC20 token. Going through such process with Dapp University without any syntax issues, I can't pass truffle test in checking if the total supply is coded in a good way.
I've tried different approaches, look at the code please. The error is as following, after $truffle test:
Using network 'development'.

Compiling ./contracts/TestToken.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...

Contract: TestToken
    1) sets the total supply upon deployment

> No events were emitted

0 passing (67ms)
  1 failing

1) Contract: TestToken
       sets the total supply upon deployment:
     TypeError: tokenInstance.balanceOf is not a function
      at Context. (test/Test.js:27:40)
      at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)

.sol code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract TestToken {
uint256 public totalSupply;

constructor (uint256 _initialSupply) public {
    totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    // allocate the initial supply
}
}
```

test.js code: (works till 7th line [error begin at , adminBalance = (...)])

```
var TestToken = artifacts.require("./TestToken.sol"); 

contract('EracoinToken', (accounts) => { 
var tokenInstance;
it('sets the total supply upon deployment', async function() { 
    const tokenInstance = await TestToken.deployed() 
    , _initialSupply = 100
    , totalSupply = await tokenInstance.totalSupply() 
    , adminBalance = await 
tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0]) 
    assert.equal(await totalSupply.toNumber(), 
_initialSupply, 'Total supply should be _initialSupply'); 
    assert.equal(await adminBalance.toNumber(), 
_initialSupply, 'Initial supply should be allocated to admin 
account!'); 
}); 
});
```

migration deploying .js code:

```
var TestToken = artifacts.require("./TestToken.sol");
let _initialSupply = 100;

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TestToken, _initialSupply);
};
```

If I run test.js till , totalSupply = await (...) it works just fine. Terminal says, that it sets the total supply upon deployment. After 7th line of test.js I expect that the terminal will say, that Total supply should be _initialSupply and the Initial supply should be allocated to admin account!

For sure there is something wrong with the code - I'm the beginner. Please give me a clue or help me to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [ERC20 Token Interface](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard), it is required that your token contract implements the following:

```
function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
```

Your test will fail trying to execute `tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0])` because there is no `balanceOf` function within your smart contract..

As for events, you will see the ERC20 Token Interface provides the following:

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
```

You can see from the implementation in the link above where these events should be emitted.